# How can I get one value in each cell of a table using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am very very new to html/css, so please dumb down your answer :). I am building a table with 4 columns. I have divs for the whole table, and divs for each individual column. This is an example of one column in html:

```
<div id="col2">
            <a href="stateunavailable.html">Indiana</a>
            <a href="stateunavailable.html">Iowa</a>
            <a href="stateunavailable.html">Kansas</a>
            <a href="stateunavailable.html">Kentucky</a>
            <a href="stateunavailable.html">Louisiana</a>
            <a href="stateunavailable.html">Maine</a>                               
            <a href="stateunavailable.html">Maryland</a>                               
            <a href="stateunavailable.html">Massachusetts</a>
            <a href="stateunavailable.html">Michigan</a>
            <a href="stateunavailable.html">Minnesota</a>                               
            <a href="stateunavailable.html">Mississippi</a>
            <a href="stateunavailable.html">Missouri</a>                               
            <a href="stateunavailable.html">Montana</a>                                             </div>
```

The following is my css code for the table:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 30px 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    text-align: center;
}
a:link {
    color:limegreen;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration: underline
        }
a:visited {
    color:orange;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
            }

#colwrap {
    disply: table;
    display:table-caption;
}

#col1 {
    display: table-cell;
}

#col2 {
    display: table-cell;
}

#col3 {
    display: table-cell;
}

#col4 {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Some of the states are not getting placed in their own cells, and some are even getting separated into two different cells. For instance, my website is showing Texas Utah as one cell instead of two different cells, and North Dakota is getting wrapped so that it is on two different cell instead of one cell. I want the end result to be four columns, one state on top of the other, 12-13 states per column.

Comment: Use https://jsfiddle.net/ or some other tool to provide working example that shows your problem. This would help others to answer your question.

Comment: It looks like you might have tabular data, so perhaps you should use table tags to mark-up the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your html snippet, it looks like you are not dividing each State into its own cell (div). You have an entire column of States in one cell.

I will suggest you have a look at [basic html tables](http://purecss.io/tables/), not because you need to use them (you can certainly build a table with divs), but because it should give you an idea of how to break up the html. A quick example below to help you see what I mean:

```html
<div id="my-table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"><a href="link">State</a></div>
    <div class="cell">State</div>
    <div class="cell">State</div>
    <div class="cell">State</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">State</div>
    <div class="cell">State</div>
    <div class="cell">State</div>
    <div class="cell">State</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @dippas I used code from both of your suggestions to get this to work the way I wanted it to. Thank you so much!